# OpenLayers WMS to Leaflet with EPSG:2170 projection

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, epsg

This is the original code for OpenLayers 2

```
        var res = [
            1000.0 / 4.0,
            1000.0 / 8.0,
            1000.0 / 16.0,
            1000.0 / 32.0,
            1000.0 / 64.0,
            1000.0 / 128.0,
            1000.0 / 256.0,
            1000.0 / 512.0,
            1000.0 / 1024.0,
            1000.0 / 2048.0
        ];

        var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(256000, 0, 640000, 256000);
        var mapOptions = {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
            ],
            resolutions: res,
            units: "m",
            projection: "EPSG:2170",
            maxExtent: extent
        };
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', mapOptions);
        map.setOptions({
            restrictedExtent: extent
        });

        layer_dof = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Slovene Ortophoto Images",
            "http://gis3d.urszr.si/pds/wms", {
                layers: "slo-gkr",
                format: "image/jpeg",
                srs: "EPSG:2170"
            }, {
                tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(512, 512),
                resolutions: res
            });
```

Now, converting that straight to Leaflet doesn't work:

```
    var res = [
        1000.0 / 4.0,
        1000.0 / 8.0,
        1000.0 / 16.0,
        1000.0 / 32.0,
        1000.0 / 64.0,
        1000.0 / 128.0,
        1000.0 / 256.0,
        1000.0 / 512.0,
        1000.0 / 1024.0,
        1000.0 / 2048.0
    ];

    var EPSG_2170 = new L.Proj.CRS(
        'EPSG:2170', 
        '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs', {
            resolutions: res,
            //origin: [-640000, -256000]
        }

    urszr = L.tileLayer.wms("http://gis3d.urszr.si/pds/wms", {
        layers: 'dtk-gkr',
        format: 'image/jpeg',
        attribution: "URSZR",
        crs: EPSG_2170,
        tileSize: 512,
        transparent: false,
    });
```

The projected coordinates are way off, and as far as I managed to figure this out is that the offset is defined in OpenLayers map extent:

```
        var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(256000, 0, 640000, 256000);
```

The coordinates in this projection start with zero, but the bounding box on [Spatial Reference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2170/) for this projection is

```
372543.8943, 5034152.5582, 631496.6208, 5197602.9212
```

**I'm stumped. What's wrong? How do I correctly configure this projection in Leaflet?**

The original site done in OpenLayers is here: 
http://spin.sos112.si/SPIN2/Javno/

```
Source: view-source:http://spin.sos112.si/SPIN2/Javno/GIS/GraficniPrikaz.aspx
```

Comment: Again, spatialreference is way off?? Check 2170 on the "official" EPSG-registry: http://www.epsg-registry.org/

Comment: Information on epsg-registry is even weirder, it says 2170 is for USA, when in fact it's a Slovenian CRS. Is it possible that the offset in the CRS is due to the map extent setting, not the actual projection? I don't see any epsg:2170 configuration in openlayers/proj4js on the site I mentioned above (spin.sos112.si)